# Blank admin page after installing SUPEE7405 in magen1.9.2.2 and error Fatal error: Class 'Unserialize_Parser'

Tags: error, supee-7405

This morning i have installed SUPEE7405 by SSH in my magento 1.9.2.2, and now i can't continue from login screen.

Before you tell me that it is a duplicate post I want to say that I think it is not, because I've tried **all** the solutions proposed in this forum and does not work any

In **error.log** appears this messages:

> 2016/01/27 08:34:59 [error] 31902#0: *5674044 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Unserialize_Parser' not found
>   in
>   /usr/share/nginx/domain.es/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
>   on line 43" while reading response header from upstream, server:
>   domain.es, request: "GET
>   /index.php/manager12/index/index/key/e2cc41f5cb2f357c963a1922eb348339/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "domain.es",
>   referrer: "http://domain.es/manager12/"

**Attached also the content of file applied.patches.list**

```
2016-01-27 06:24:10 UTC | SUPEE-7405-CE-1-9-2-2 | CE_1.9.2.2 | v1 | 4d945a4014f384b275cad0d00729478c7fd2266d | Tue Jan 19 15:19:16 2016 +0200 | 71d7188883..4d945a4014
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


2016-01-27 08:42:04 UTC | SUPEE-7616 | CE_1.9.2.2-CE_1.8.0.0 | v1 | 1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1 | Tue Dec 8 12:53:31 2015 +0200 | e1fc3c59c9587427b8a9c88655715f27afbfe970..1609c0d0be86473d357346fa51f93c12b365d7a1
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
```

Please I need help because I do not get to find out where the error

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, to me it looks like you have not applied patch 6788.

Indeed the `Unserialize_Parser` class comes from `lib/Unserialize/Parser.php` which was only included with patch 6788.

Comment: In December update Magento to 1.9.2.2 i know that this version includes 6788, is correct?

Comment: In addition I can not download the 6788 version for Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: @RafaelPastorGarcía yes I know but to me it seems like it was not applied properly. Is the file I mentionned present in your Magento folder ?

Comment: Indeed, you're right, even don't exists the "unserialize" folder in  "lib" folder

Comment: How can i fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I reckon you should try upgrading Magento again to 1.9.2.2. Make a backup of your current Magento folder and do a manual upgrade so you're sure the files are here.

Comment: ok, I'm doing a backup and now go up the files of version 1.9.2.2, should overwrite existing files? when you upload the files, I overwrite if I lose the patch 7405?

Comment: Yes you will, but you can upgrade directly to 1.9.2.3 so you can get it

Comment: good idea, thank you, and if I upload files to FTP version 1.9.2.3 directly and overwrite will be updated good to 1.9.2.3?
I have always updated with Magento Connect

Comment: @DigitalPianism i install 6788 patch also but after login its blank page

Comment: @ND17 check your server error logs as well as magento logs and let me know the error

Comment: @DigitalPianism its give this error Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Importexport_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: @ND17 does that file exists: `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Helper/Data.php` ?

Comment: yes its exists and its solved by my silly mistake config.xml is not exists in ImportExport etc folder

Comment: @ND17 congratulations then we did it ;) feel free to mark the answer as solved

Comment: I wish to mark the answer as solved but this question is not mine