# Blank admin screen after upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9.2.4 via Magento Connect

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, upgrade

I chose to upgrade via magento connect and am now getting a blank screen for admin with an error when printed of

> Fatal error: Class 'Unserialize_Parser' not found in
>   /var/www/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php on
>   line 43

I've cleared cache and session folders, is it related to certain patches? how can i troubleshoot/resolve please?

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99120/blank-admin-page-after-installing-supee7405-in-magen1-9-2-2-and-error-fatal-erro

Comment: Have you update lib ?

Comment: I have added the 'lib' directory and its subfolders but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Checking given file /var/www/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php on line 43

```
class Mage_Core_Helper_UnserializeArray
{
    public function unserialize($str)
    {
        $parser = new Unserialize_Parser();
        return $parser->unserialize($str);
    }
}
```

Check in lib folder have no directory Unserialize so it trigger error.

Download fresh magento and upload it to lib folder.

Comment: Nothings worked yet but thanks for the suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on this issue few days back. Unistall the local.xml and then re-install magento 1.9. It worked for me. Let me know your response.